# can't access phpmyadmin in ubuntu 18.04, php 5.6 apache2

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I have defined two virtual hosts inside `sites-enabled` directory of apahce2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

         ServerAdmin webmaster@sub.domain.in
        ServerName sub.domain.in
        ServerAlias www.sub.domain
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub/public_html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>


   # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
<VirtualHost *:443>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@sub.domain.in
        ServerName sub.domain.in
        ServerAlias www.sub.domain
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/sub.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/sub.key
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration is working fine for all of the subdomains, but there is one problem I can't access phpmyadmin any more by visiting `http://ip/phpmyadmin`
what configuration should I change to make phpmyadmin accessible using the web server.

Comment: Check the Apache error logs for more information on what is wrong

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted the question I just want to know what's wrong in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access phpmyadmin when virtual hosts are enabled in apache2 you need to just create another subdomain for phpmyadmin
with following configurations under `sites-available` in `phpmyadmin.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin adminn@example.local
   ServerName phpmyadmin.example.local
   DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin
   <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
   </Directory>
   LogLevel notice
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
   ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

After this do

```
sudo a2ensite phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 reload
```

now visit the subdomain phpmyadmin.mydomain.com and it should be right there

**NOTE: if you are using ssl you also have to define a virtual host on port 443 with ssl config in the same file**